# Looking for Python Video Processing Library using GPU

Tags: python, video, gpu, video-processing

I need to iterate through every single frame in a video and do something on that frame. Right now I'm using [scikit-video](http://www.scikit-video.org/stable/io.html) library and just basically do:

```
vid = skvideo.io.vreader(vid_path)
for frame in vid:
   # Do something
```

I wonder if there are any libraries that utilizes GPU to do this job? I have a GTX 1070 so I want to take advantage of it. Or is there any space for optimization?

Comment: have you heard of opencv? It has CUDA support. http://opencv.org/platforms/cuda.html

Comment: @theAlse I just looked it up and it seems that there's only C++ code available for video processing using opencv that has GPU support. But thanks, if there's no better solution I might switch to C++ on this task.

Comment: From [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow "

Comment: @Paler, I think it offers good python API for video processing. http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Comment: @theAlse Thanks, I saw that but I feel like it will still use cpu to do that. I found their [GPU module documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/gpu/doc/gpu.html), however it doesn't seem to support python yet.